# Replace string in different file

Tags: replace, tcl

The following is memory directory

Every directory need to enter it and modify the following three files :

1. `hcell.list`
2. `SmicDR1T_cal40_log_ll_sali_p1mx_1tm_121825.drc`
3. `SmicSP1R_cal40_LL_sali_p1mtx_11182533.lvs`

The above three file has content "`TPSRAM_256X120`" and I want to replace it with its own directory path name.

How should I do it?

```
 SPRF_256X34      SPSRAM_128X30    SPSRAM_192X16   SPSRAM_240X48  SPSRAM_2944X72  SPSRAM_480X48  SPSRAM_512X8    SPSRAM_72X8     SPSRAM_960X60_WEM  SROM_8192X8
 command.log      SPSRAM_1024X14   SPSRAM_128X64    SPSRAM_2048X17  SPSRAM_240X56  SPSRAM_304X128  SPSRAM_480X64  SPSRAM_5376X17  SPSRAM_8192X12  SPSRAM_960X8       SROM_960X26
filenames.log    SPSRAM_1024X16   SPSRAM_152X8     SPSRAM_2048X8   SPSRAM_240X72  SPSRAM_32X64    SPSRAM_480X66  SPSRAM_5376X80  SPSRAM_8192X20  SPSRAM_960X80      TPSRAM_1920X9
 mem_new.list     SPSRAM_11520X28  SPSRAM_16384X34  SPSRAM_240X10   SPSRAM_240X8   SPSRAM_384X19   SPSRAM_480X96  SPSRAM_544X20   SPSRAM_8192X34  SPSRAM_960X96      TPSRAM_256X120
SPRF_240X20      SPSRAM_120X72    SPSRAM_16384X38  SPSRAM_240X152  SPSRAM_240X88  SPSRAM_4352X8   SPSRAM_496X44  SPSRAM_544X21   SPSRAM_8192X52  SROM_1024X16
 SPRF_240X32      SPSRAM_120X80    SPSRAM_16384X40  SPSRAM_240X17   SPSRAM_240X9   SPSRAM_4480X8   SPSRAM_496X82  SPSRAM_5760X32  SPSRAM_8192X72  SROM_1440X14
SPRF_240X82      SPSRAM_120X88    SPSRAM_1920X56   SPSRAM_240X18   SPSRAM_240X96  SPSRAM_480X128  SPSRAM_496X86  SPSRAM_64X22    SPSRAM_8192X8   SROM_1888X26
 SPRF_240X86      SPSRAM_1216X40   SPSRAM_1920X60   SPSRAM_240X22   SPSRAM_256X8   SPSRAM_480X144  SPSRAM_512X10  SPSRAM_64X24    SPSRAM_8192X9   SROM_4096X8
SPRF_240X86_WEM  SPSRAM_1280X32   SPSRAM_1920X8    SPSRAM_240X34   SPSRAM_2688X8  SPSRAM_480X16   SPSRAM_512X17  SPSRAM_64X48    SPSRAM_960X24   SROM_512X16
 SPRF_240X90      SPSRAM_128X16    SPSRAM_1920X9    SPSRAM_240X40   SPSRAM_2880X8  SPSRAM_480X32   SPSRAM_512X27  SPSRAM_720X12   SPSRAM_960X60   SROM_736X14
```

Answer (score 0):

get all the directories:

```
set all_dir [glob -type d -nocomplain -dir $dirname *]
```

in foreach loop open your files: hcell.list, SmicDR1T_cal40_log_ll_sali_p1mx_1tm_121825.drc, SmicSP1R_cal40_LL_sali_p1mtx_11182533.lvs

```
set r [open [file join $dir hcell.list] r]
```

Now replace your content using regsub:

```
regsub "TPSRAM_256X120" $line [pwd]
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace a value in a file with another, while writing that file back to the same file, you want code like this:

```
proc replaceValue {filename changeThis toThis {backupExtension ""}} {
    set mapping [list $changeThis $toThis]

    # Read and transform the file
    set f [open $filename]
    set content [string map $mapping [read $f]]
    close $f

    # Make backup if requested
    if {$backupExtension ne ""} {
        file rename $filename $filename$backupExtension
    }

    # Write the new contents back
    set f [open $filename "w"]
    puts -nonewline $f $content
    close $f
}
```

This is only suitable for files up to a couple of hundred megabytes (assuming you've got plenty of memory) but it is *easy*.

Then, to apply the alteration to everything in a directory, use `glob` to list the directory contents, `foreach` to go over the list, and that procedure to apply the transformation.

```
# Glob patterns in quotes just because of Markdown formatting bug
foreach filename [glob -directory /the/base/directory "*/*.list" "*/*.drc" "*/*.lvs"] {
    # Make backups into .bak
    replaceValue $filename TPSRAM_256X120 $filename ".bak"
}
```